# Intellij and Github are acting very strangely

Tags: github, intellij-idea

my issue is that I'm building a web app. I have added base directory like `<project_dir>\webapp and <project_dir>\webapp\META-INF and <project_dir>\webapp\views and <project_dir>\src\main\resources\assets`

the disturbing part, is that intellij, git, github desktop are acting like these resources don't exist.

The only way to make these directories appear is to commit a test file under each directory. But the issue is that when I delete that test file, the directories disappear.

What's going on ?

Comment: Could you please attach screemshots describing you project structure from File Manager and IDE?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't. I've already updated the project so many times. I think i'll close the subject.